# Showing 1000+bar data in jqplot horizontal bar graph

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, jqplot, large-data

I am using jqplot to render the **horizontal bar graph in a popup,**I have 1000+ data to render, calculating the container width dynamically based on bar count.

Issue: It works **fine till 700+** data but as it **exceeds 1000-1000+ bars do not get rendered** instead only **x axis, y axis valus and labels alone comes**.

I have **customized angular directive** to which I am sending the bar data, I am not sure if that is an issue.(If that would be the case then why the labels and axis values are coming but bars not drawing)

Comment: can you post a simplified example of the code (e.g. to jsfiddle) showing the problem?

Comment: I have a set of object like:
data=[[x,y],[x1,y1],[x2,y2]................[x1000+, y1000+]]....
 And I am fetching this set from some other set were i have lot of values through looping.